# Equivalent datatype in entityframework core for postgressql's jsonb

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I am using EntityFrameworkCore and PostgresSql in my application. Further I am using code first approach to generate the db tables. Now there is a column for which I want datatype as jsonb in postgres but I do not see such datatype in EntityFrameworkCore. In C# I tried with adding an attribute as [Column(TypeName="jsonb")] but still datatpe in postgres is text and I am able to insert non-jsonb data in my column using insert script which I don't want. So just want to check is there a way to fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the generated migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a `string`, try using the [JsonDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsondocument?view=net-6.0) type.